# What kind of tree has leaves like this?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

Shot taken in Spring, [image]on May 22, 2020 in a forest in Haliburton, Ontario.

Comment: Your other question also shows a Beech.

Comment: Please see the guidance at https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info for species ID questions and use that tag when you ask for ID.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [beech tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beech). From the leaves only it is hard to say which species it is exactly, but given your location it is probably the [North America Beech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagus_grandifolia), *Fagus Grandifolia*.

See this leave from the second Wikipedia article for comparision:

[image]